# ng2-select easy way to get nice css

Tags: css, angular, angular2-directives

I am using ng2-select in angular2 application (I am new to angular).
I am trying to change the css of the ng2-select.
When I look on my object I can see it css is coming from bootstrap, ng-select css  and more I can see that the ng-select directive is built from:

```
<div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown form-control open" tabindex="0">
<div></div>
<span class="ui-select-match">
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</span>
<input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="false" autocorrect="off" class="ui-select-search input-xs" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Choose Modifiers">

<!--template bindings={}-->

<!--template bindings={}-->
```

but I want to get a nice select box - something like:
and don't know how to get it

```
select {
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    background-color: lightblue;
    background-transparency: 0.5;
    background-position: right 15px top 22px;
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    margin-left :20px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the styles you want into your stylesheet that is declared in the DOM after the CSS that is currently styling it -- and dont forget to at least match the specificity of the rules that are currently declared.

Comment: Thanks, I did it and it kind of worked. The problem is that the ng2-select is build from a lot of things and the multiple choice and single are different. if anyone have a nice css to share it will be great if not I will share my css once it is stabilized.

Comment: It seems like you want something fairly specific that goes beyond the scope of the question. If my answer worked for you, please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is correct and very help full and I have tried to mark it as correct but I don't have enough reputation... once I will have enough I promise to mark it. Thanks again

Comment: All good. Glad to help. Dont forget to mark it as correct when you can ;)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I've since found a better way, say for the `select-input` since it is an `input` you can add an `id=""` to the HTML element and reference it in the `.css/.scss` w/ `input#id { }`. Is much cleaner than the `:host /deep/`. This works with wrapped controls like `kendo-maskedtextbox`, etc.

The chosen answer isn't very useful in this instance; I tried that way and got nowhere.

Doing more research I came across [Component Style guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) which uses `:host` and `/deep/` attributes alongside the components CSS classes to give proper depth exposure for the styling.

I ended up using these three classes to style ng2-select:

```
:host /deep/ .btn-secondary, 
:host /deep/ .ui-select-choices,
:host /deep/ .ui-select-search
{
    ...
}
```